# JavaScript without "popup" window in script?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the send-button (id="Button1") to send a mail only when the caption is correct (string1 === string2). How and were, do I get this to work, in the button itself or in the script?

<strike>I also not want the popup to show telling me "TRUE", same with false, I do want the "alert" to open and tell me when its wrong, but not sign after that telling me "FALSE". I have tried without the "return false;" and "return true;", but that only gives me "undefined".</strike> **EDIT:** Just fixed this, I didn't realised I had "alert(ValidCaptcha());" it should be "ValidCaptcha();". But still need help with the first question.

```js
function Captcha(){
         var alpha = new Array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','Å','Ä','Ö',
            'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','å','ä','ö', 
                '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
         var i;
         for (i=0;i<6;i++){
             var a = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
             var b = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
             var c = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
             var d = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
             var e = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
             var f = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
             var g = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
                          }
             var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' '+ f + ' ' + g;
             document.getElementById("mainCaptcha").innerHTML = code
             document.getElementById("mainCaptcha").value = code
           }
    function ValidCaptcha(){
         var string1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('mainCaptcha').value);
         var string2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
         
      if (string1 === string2){
                return true;
         }
      else
      {        
         alert('Wrong, try again');
              return false;
              }
    }
    function removeSpaces(string){
         return string.split(' ').join('');
    }
```

```css
.capt{
        background-color:LightGray;
        width: 300px;
        height:100px;
        
    }

    #mainCaptcha{
        position: relative;
        left : 60px;
        top: 5px;
        
    }

    #refresh{
        position:relative;
        left:230px;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        bottom:45px;
    }

    #txtInput, #Button1{
        position: relative;
        left:20px;
        bottom: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<body onload="Captcha();"> 
       <div class="capt"> 
       <h2 style="-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none;-o-user-select:none;" unselectable="on" onselectstart="return false;" onmousedown="return false;" type="text" id="mainCaptcha"></h2>
       <p><input type="button" id="refresh" onclick="Captcha();"/></p>            <input type="text" id="txtInput"/>    
       
       <button value="Send" id="Button1" type="submit" onclick="alert(ValidCaptcha());">SEND</button>
       </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing ValidCaptcha inside alert that's why its returning alert with your return True and false I removed the alert call and it works fine

```js
function Captcha(){
         var alpha = new Array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','Å','Ä','Ö',
            'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','å','ä','ö', 
                '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
         var i;
         for (i=0;i<6;i++){
             var a = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
             var b = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
             var c = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
             var d = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
             var e = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
             var f = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
             var g = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
                          }
             var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' '+ f + ' ' + g;
             document.getElementById("mainCaptcha").innerHTML = code
             document.getElementById("mainCaptcha").value = code
           }
    function ValidCaptcha(){
         var string1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('mainCaptcha').value);
         var string2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
         
      if (string1 === string2){
                return true;
         }
      else
      {        
         alert('Wrong, try again');
              return false;
              }
    }
    function removeSpaces(string){
         return string.split(' ').join('');
    }
```

```css
.capt{
        background-color:LightGray;
        width: 300px;
        height:100px;
        
    }

    #mainCaptcha{
        position: relative;
        left : 60px;
        top: 5px;
        
    }

    #refresh{
        position:relative;
        left:230px;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        bottom:45px;
    }

    #txtInput, #Button1{
        position: relative;
        left:20px;
        bottom: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<body onload="Captcha();"> 
       <div class="capt"> 
       <h2 style="-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none;-o-user-select:none;" unselectable="on" onselectstart="return false;" onmousedown="return false;" type="text" id="mainCaptcha"></h2>
       <p><input type="button" id="refresh" onclick="Captcha();"/></p>            <input type="text" id="txtInput"/>    
       
       <button value="Send" id="Button1" type="submit" onclick="ValidCaptcha();">SEND</button>
       </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Yes. However, even if its wrong it does still send me a e-mail. :(

Comment: can you share your logic for sending mail

Comment: Thats great Rahul, @Rahul Khanna but I don't understand how to do so.

Comment: I mean post your whole code so I can figure that out